# How to reattach stdin to console window after pipe?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, console, sh

I'm doing one of overthewire's CTFs, this challenge requires sending some characters that are hard to copy and paste into the process `narnia0`. Inside that process, a system call to `/bin/sh` is made, but because the standard output of `xxd` is redirected to the standard input of `narnia0`, I'm not able to make use of the shell.

How do I get around this? How do I reattach `narnia0` standard input to my terminal's standard output after the standard output of `xxd` is consumed (or the process ends)?

This is the shell code:

`echo 3030303030303030303030303030303030303030efbeadde | xxd -r -p | ./narnia0`

**Edit**

Here's a quick example:

Example.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  system("/bin/sh");
  return 0;
}
```

Compile:

`gcc -o example ./example.c`

Example illustrating issue:

`echo bla | ./example`

This results in:

`/bin/sh: line 1: bla: command not found`

Which is the desired behaviour, but after that how do I reattach stdin to my terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe removing `xxd` from the problem helps?

```
(printf '\x30...\xef\xbe\xad\xde'; cat) | ./narnia0
```

Alternatively, just stay with `echo`:

```
(echo -ne '\x30...\xef\xbe\xad\xde'; cat) | ./narnia0
```

**Edit**: Added `cat` to add input/output to the subsequent shell

Comment: Same issue, I've added an example above

Comment: I've added a subshell + `cat` to give you input/output

Comment: Generally it isn't necessary: programs are either interactive or piping, but not both. But in the case where you want your script to inject/modify something into your program's piped input, you can either catch all the input in the bash script, then stream it out to the program, or cleverly use sed and awk to manipulate the piped input.